# How can a webapp show whether polling is on or off, without looking like it is stuck?

Tags: gui-design, interactive-ui, application-state

[ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/usermanual#background-polling)'s web client polls a server every N seconds. Polling can be on or off.

The UI is currently a clickable GIF image:

- [image: polling] when polling is on
- [image: not polling] when polling is off
- Clicking the icon switches on/off (on by default)

PROBLEM: To new users, the polling icon looks like the webapp is having trouble loading something.

QUESTION: What better image could be used to convey the fact that polling is on/off?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely avoid using that animated icon, as it is very strongly associated with "loading", and gives the impression that loading is incomplete.

You want to show state as clearly "on", or "off". In the real world, people use buttons and switches to perform on or off operations, so it should be clear if you present them with some kind of labeled switch or slider.

Something like this would do the job:

[image]

EDIT:
In answer to your question, you could put [a standard refresh icon](https://www.google.nl/search?q=polling&espv=2&biw=1140&bih=757&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=1zfLVMT_FcPCPIuFgYgB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=refresh%20icon) beside the words "off" and "on" to indicate that this is controlling refreshing of data, or you could label the slider with the words "Auto Refresh" (the term "polling" may be too technical for some users).

Comment: Any way to express what you said while also conveying that it is about polling, maybe? Like an enabled/disabled radar or something?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Edited my answer with some suggestions. Hope that helps. :)